# Playing audio from amr on Android

Tags: android, audio, amr

I can receive a byte array from a `Socket`. I need to play audio from this byte array - the audio is encoded with AMR 8000Hz.

I found that I can play AMR audio with `MediaPlayer`. However, `MediaPlayer` can't play music from byte array, and I don't want to write them to file.

Is there a way to play AMR sound from byte array on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android framework allows you to play back audio data directly from memory using the `AudioTrack` class; the drawback is that the audio must already be decoded into PCM data.  If you are lucky enough to target Android 4.1, there are new APIs that allow you to decode the data separately so it can be passed to `AudioTrack` (see `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec`).  However, prior to that there were no exposed APIs for encoding/decoding beyond `MediaRecorder` and `MediaPlayer`.

If targeting a version of Android prior to 4.1 (which I imagine you probably are) you have two options:

- Find a 3rd party decoder for the AMR data so you can pass it on to `AudioTrack`
- Save your data to a file (even temporarily) so it can be handed to `MediaPlayer`

HTH

Comment: Thank you, I thought the same. Do you know any third party libs to decode AMR to PCM?

Comment: Google search pulled up this one.  Looks like it might be native code, so you would need the NDK: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/